# Parallel loop gives minor perfromance gain, how to optimize?

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing, plinq

I have following code which actually DE-serialize a CSV into objects. I tried using Foreach also with Parallelism, but I get a minor gain. I want to know that how can I optimize this code to better utilize parallel processing capabilities. I have i7 with 8GB ram and processing 1000-2000 records in a csv string.

```
    private List<Summary> deserializeCSV(string pSource, int pageSize)
    {
        List<Summary> ret = new List<Summary>(pageSize);

        string[] lines = pSource.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

        Parallel.For(1, lines.Length - 1, i =>
        {
            string[] col = lines[i].Split(',');
            ret.Add(new Summary
            {
                Complaint_Type = col[0],
                Product = col[1],
                ProductGroup = col[2],
                Brand = col[3],
                Each_UPC = col[4],
                SUBJECTCATEGORY_DESC = col[5],
                GROUP_DESC = col[6],
                SUBGROUP_DESC = col[7],
                SUBJECT_DESC = col[8],
                State = col[9],
                CITY = col[10],
                FullZip = col[11],
                Zip = col[12],
                IssueDate = DateTime.Parse(col[13]),
                ComplaintsCount = Single.Parse(col[14]),
                Gender = col[15],
                AgeBucket = col[16],
                Population = Single.Parse(col[17]),
                _RowID = int.Parse(col[18]),
                _RowIDComp = int.Parse(col[19]),
                ComplaintsCount_New = Single.Parse(col[20]),
                Population_New = Single.Parse(col[21]),
                Country = col[22],
                _ID = long.Parse(col[23]),
                C40_CODE = col[24]
            });
        });

        return ret;
    }
```

I observed that if I don't add the de-serilized object [ means rather than ret.Add(new Summary, var temp = new Summary] into my returnable list (but only assign values), it gives me better performance. Is there something wrong with this initialization List ret = new List(pageSize); or something else?

**EDIT-1**
My scenario is that I have a csv contained in-memory pages and I have to process those pages to extract some summary information from them. This is a time consuming task and I was looking to optimize the processing time using parallel processing.

Comment: Parallelizing CSV parsing is not easy and giving a useful answer is too broad of a task. See https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=parallelize+csv+parsing for some strategies.

Comment: I mentioned that its not a csv file, but a csv string

Comment: @asif That's not really a relevant difference to usr's point.

Answer (score 2):

First of, that code is not thread-safe. *If* `Parallel.For` decides to use more than one thread (that's right, it might also decide not to), you'll have several threads accessing the same list, which itself is not thread-safe. You should use a `ConcurrentBag<T>`, for example.

Second, I don't think that kind of work is worth parallelizing. How long does it take to execute it sequentially? Milliseconds? You're simply parsing strings and creating objects, there's no expensive computation going on.

Comment: @asif Nothing in your edit is relevant to this answer.